# Synchronisation QField - QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

I'm using QGIS 3.22.4 and QFiedl v2.1.2 with the latest QFieldSync plugin. Lately at the time of synchronization, I get a message like: `the original project path on "geopackage: C:/.../..." was not found.`

I tried to create simple paths etc... but nothing works. Before the new QField and QFieldSync updates everything was working fine.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Win 10`, `QGIS 3.22.13 'Białowieża' LTR`, `QField v2.5.5` and an Android phone.

If I am correct about your difficulty it seems that Google have introduced a secuity policy regards where Android Apps can access data.

What I have done is as follows

1. create the project and QField Sync it on the laptop
2. create a folder on the Phone let's say `wxyz`, then connect the Phone to the laptop via cable and copy the project folder from Win10 folder to the `wxyz` folder on the Phone.
3. open Qfield on the Phone and `Import` the data from the `wxyz` folder into QField.
4. carry out whatever you need to do.
5. `Export` the project data from QField back the the `wxyz` folder and from there back to the Win10 folder.

More information is here,
[QField Docs: Import and open local project](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/projects/)

[Field Users Sit Down, We Need to Talk About Storage Access on Android](https://www.opengis.ch/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%ef%bf%bc/)

[Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk)